# Задачи Яндекса на должность Android Developer. Спорный вопрос. Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Tags: java, android

Есть [3 задачки](https://yandex.ru/jobs/vacancies/dev/dev_android/) для прохождения собеседования в Yandex на должность Android Developer. После выполнения этих 3 заданий мне сообщили, что я не выполнил ни одного задания верно, хотелось бы услышать от вас, где у меня ошибки.

- **Задача 1**: Какие объекты доступны для сборщика мусора на момент вызова `System.gc()` и почему?

  ```
  public class GCTest {
      static class A {
          private String myName;
          public A(String myName) {
              this.myName = myName;
          }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          A a1 = new A("a1");
          A a2 = new A("a2");
          ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
          list.add(a1);
          A[] mas = new A[2];
          mas[0] = a2;
          a2 = a1;
          clear(mas);
          a1 = null;
          a2 = null;
          System.gc();
          // дальше идет какой-то код
          ...
      }

      private static void clear(A[] mas) {
          mas = null;
      }
  }
  ```

  **Мой ответ**: Массив `new A[2]` из строки `A[] mas = new A[2]` будет очищен, так как мы выполняем функцию, которая зануляет этот массив (`mas = null`). Также будет очищен объект `new A("a2")`, так как мы теряем на него ссылку в строке `a2 = a1`, соответственно он ссылается уже на объект `new A("a1")`. А далее мы зануляем массив, как я писал выше, поэтому больше никто не ссылается на на объект `new A[2]`.
- **Задача 2**: Перечислите все проблемы, которые вы видите в данном коде:

  ```
  public class Generator {
      private static final Map<byte[], byte[]> cache = new HashMap<byte[], byte[]>();

      public static byte[] generate(byte[] src) {
          byte[] generated = cache.get(src);
          if (generated == null) {
              synchronized (cache) {
                  generated = cache.get(src);
                  if (generated == null) {
                      generated = doGenerate(src);
                      cache.put(src, generated);
                  }
              }
          }
          return generated;
      }

      private static byte[] doGenerate(byte[] src) {...}
          // ...
      }
  ```

  **Мой ответ**: Я написал, что использование `byte[]` в качестве ключа HashMap недопустимо, так как у `byte[]` метод `Hashcode()` реализован на алгоритме [Park-Miller RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator). `Hashcode()` у `byte[]` реализован так же, как и у `Object`, точно так же метод `equals()` будет работать, как у `Object` и будет сравнивать ссылки на объект, а не само содержание объектов (как обычно людям кажется), соответственно на основании этого я написал, что данная коллекция будет работать некорректно.

  Далее я написал, что также все строки кода, в которых выполняется добавление данных в коллекцию или удаление не имеет смысла, так как мы используем в качестве ключа `byte[]`.

  Далее я написал, что код:

  ```
  if (generated == null) {
      synchronized (cache) {
          generated = cache.get(src);
          if (generated == null) {
              generated = doGenerate(src);
              cache.put(src, generated);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  слишком растянут и имеют лишние строки, которые повторяются далее.
- **Задача 3**: Есть две задачи: Task 1 и Task 2. Стек Activity для Task 1: `A,B,C,D`. Стек Activity для Task 2: `X,Y,Z`.

  После выполнения указанного действия для всех пунктов в ответе необходимо указать:

  1. Как будет выглядеть стек Activity для задач. Например, `Task 1: A,B,C,D; Task 2: X,Y,Z`;
  2. Историю того, как будут изменяться стеки при нажатии кнопки <kbd>BACK</kbd>, пока не возвратимся в Home screen. Например: `A,B,C,D - back -> A,B,C - back -> A,B - back -> A - back -> Home screen`;

  а) У всех Activity установлен `launchMode="standard"`. В текущий момент отображается *Activity Z*. *Из Activity Z* отправляется Intent на открытие *Activity D*.

  б) У всех Activity установлен `launchMode="standard"`, но только у *Activity D* установлен `launchMode="singleTop"`. В текущий момент отображается *Activity Z*. Из *Activity Z* отправляется Intent на открытие *Activity D*.

  в) У всех Activity установлен `launchMode="standard"`, но только у *Activity D* установлен `launchMode="singleTask"`. В текущий момент отображается *Activity Z*. Из *Activity Z* отправляется Intent на открытие *Activity D*.

  **Мой ответ**: При ответе в их форме я в конце прокомментировал мои действия, здесь не будут, просто дам [ссылку](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) на описание режимов Activity, там есть таблица в середине с полным описанием.

  1. а) Task 1: A,B,C,D; Task 2: X,Y,Z,D;

     б) `A,B,C,D - back -> A,B,C - back -> A,B - back -> A - back -> Home screen`; `X,Y,Z,D - back -> X,Y,Z - back -> X,Y - back -> X - back -> Home screen`;
  2. а) Task 1: A,B,C,D; Task 2: X,Y,Z,D;

     б) `A,B,C,D - back -> A,B,C - back -> A,B - back -> A - back -> Home screen`; `X,Y,Z,D - back -> X,Y,Z - back -> X,Y - back -> X - back -> Home screen`;
  3. а) Task 1: A,B,C,D; Task 2: X,Y,Z;

     б) `A,B,C,D - back -> A,B,C - back -> A,B - back -> A - back -> Home screen`; `X,Y,Z - back -> X,Y - back -> X - back -> Home screen`;

Я также искал в просторах интернета ответы на эти задачи, кроме 3, и нашёл пару ссылок, **на первую задачу** [отвечают](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20487473/3789850), что сборщик мусора отчистит ноль объектов; а я ответил, что два: массив и объект. Я не совсем понял, почему это так? Почему зануление массива не влияет на сам массив, почему он всё равно существует?

По поводу **второй задачи** были споры, что коллекция не является потокобезопасной; никто не писал по поводу ключа в качестве `byte[]`. Но как из их задачи вообще можно понять, что они там хотят сделать? Там же нету дополнений, что всё выполняется в несколько потоков. Так-то я в курсе, что коллекция не потокобезопасна, и для этого есть специальные реализации синхронизированных коллекций.

**Прошу от вас конструктивных ответов**, так как у меня завязался спор с сотрудником из Yandex, и мы договорились, что пусть более компетентные люди с большим опытом попробуют дать ответ на эти задачи и растолкуют мне мои недочёты. Если я был прав хотя бы в одном из ответов, то по этому вопросу будет непосредственное разбирательство внутри их компании; а я на 99% уверен, что 3 задачу я решил верно, и там варианты ответа не такие размазанные, как во 2 задаче, где каждый может найти свою неточность или огрех.

Заранее благодарю за ответы, ибо для меня это дело принципа!

Comment: Я проходил данный этап у Яндекс, ещё зеленным. У вас в каждом ответе ошибки и неточности и не надо ругаться, просто просите ласково feedback. В первом вопросе вы разобрались, это явно и очень просто. Во втором вы раскручиваете идею которой может и не быть в коде, а там стандартные проблемы хеширования и всем известные проблемы hashMap в Java, и обратите как идет sync для него, частично вам ответили. Последняя задача у вас только 2-й вариант правильный в первом ошибка, а третий не верен, вы не до конца понимаете принцип, там будет тип того Home: X, Y, Z, A, B, C, D. Удачи,учатся на ошибках)

Comment: Пипец. Это Яндекс такие вопросы задаёт или так везде? Сложно вроде. И причём тут андроид девелоперская и сборка мусора?

Comment: @СергейГрушин Потому что Android неизбежно сопряжён с Java, поверьте, с опытом эти вопросы становятся детскими

Answer (score 25, accepted):

За 3-ю задачу говорить не буду, т.к. android не занимаюсь.

В первой задаче ответ действительно неверный. Изучайте Java. В том числе смотрите про передачу параметров в Java.

По второй задаче ответ во-первых далеко неполный (можно час обсуждать проблемы в этом коде, без преувеличений). Очевидно, что в коде представлен кэш. Попробуйте подумать о том, как он будет использоваться в клиентском коде. Какими вообще свойствами обладают кэши. Во-вторых, та часть ответа, которую вы представили на тему hashCode верна, но не всегда. Посмотрите на то, какие есть варианты реализации hashCode в JVM.

Более развернутый ответ давать не собираюсь, т.к. считаю подобное поведение некорректным по отношению к Яндексу и другим соискателям.

Comment: Давайте я ещё намекну, что параметры передаются по значению (надеюсь, это не слишком повредит Яндексу), и что имеет смысл посмотреть в отладчике, какой эффект имеет метод `clear`.

Comment: Какой же я днище! Я реально в попыхах не обратил внимание на саму функцию, а тупо посмотрел на то,  что происходит зануление и всё и мозгом не подумал,  что зануление происходило не самого массива, а лишь её копии внутри функции, вот это я реально лоз

Comment: @BORSHEVIK: Это была достаточно подлая ловушка, функция называлась `clear`.

Answer (score 8):

Во второй задаче помимо использования `byte[]` в качестве ключей (в конкретном коде может это и не проблема, сравнивать ключи по ссылке иногда может быть нормально) серьёзная проблема — это ламерская реализация double-checked locking. Запись в `HashMap` охраняется локом, но первое чтение — нет. В результате поведение может быть неспецифицированным. Возможно что угодно — произвольное исключение, неверный результат или даже зацикливание с полным подвисанием потока. DCL можно применять с volatile-переменной, которую вы контролируете (и то осторожно, там есть тонкости с публикацией объекта), но со структурой данных, которую вы не контролируете — ни в коем случае.

В данном случае надо не мучать киску, а использовать `ConcurrentHashMap`. Если хочется вычислять значение не более одного раза для каждого ключа и Java-8 использовать нельзя, то можно сделать `ConcurrentHashMap<KeyType, AtomicReference<ValueType>>` и реализацию вроде:

```
private static final Map<KeyType, AtomicReference<ValueType>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static ValueType generate(KeyType key) {
    AtomicReference<ValueType> ref = cache.get(key);
    if(ref == null) {
        ref = new AtomicReference<>();
        AtomicReference<ValueType> oldRef = cache.putIfAbsent(key, ref);
        if(oldRef != null) ref = oldRef;
    }
    ValueType value = ref.get();
    if(value == null) {
        synchronized(ref) {
            value = ref.get();
            if(value == null) {
                value = doGenerate(key);
                ref.set(value);
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Примерно такая идея. Так у вас для каждого ключа вычисляется значение единожды, и при этом решается ещё одна проблема: при вычислении значения для одного ключа работа с остальными не блокируется.

В Java-8 то же самое гораздо проще:

```
public static ValueType generate(KeyType key) {
    return cache.computeIfAbsent(key, this::doGenerate);
}
```

Правда оно вроде как блокирует целый node, а не одну запись, но в node нечасто бывает больше одной записи.

Соответственно ваш ответ по второй задаче в корне неверен в том смысле, что вы даже понятие DCL не упомянули.

Comment: Да, есть такое дело, данный анти-паттерн не был мной упомянут, нужно было написать, что для такого паттерна необходимо было бы добавить модификатор **volatile** для переменной

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, вас бы на этом точно засыпали. Модификатор volatile на какой переменной вы имеете в виду?

Comment: На перменной **chache**

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, не возьмут вас в яндекс.

Comment: Не велика беда, а раз вы такой умный, то поясните свою точку зрения по поводу **Volatile**

Answer (score 7):

По трейтьей задаче. Сначала надо понять как получили два таска, т.е. что это вообще такое (допускаю, что вы об это прекрасно знаете, но для ясности опишем).

Запускаем с home screen'а активити: A, из которого переходим в B, дальше в C, и D. 
Жмем home. Запускаем с home screen'а активити X, из него Y, и него Z.

Пример. Есть приложение sms и приложение dialer и в том и другом можно вызвать активти списка контактов. И вот в sms открыли список контактов и в dialer'е собираемся открыть тот же список контактов. Дальше варианты:

a) Мы находимся в task 2, у которого стек XYZ. Переходим в D и теперь задача узнать какие стеки будут у каждого из task'ов. task1 так и останется ABCD. task2 станет XYZD. В standard mode Активити D создастся и добавится в стек task2, не влияя никак на task1. В результате последовательного нажатия back:

Task1=ABCD, Task2=XYZD ->
Task1=ABCD, Task2=XYZ ->
Task1=ABCD, Task2=XY ->
Task1=ABCD, Task2=X ->
Task1=ABCD, Task2 завершится (стек пустой) перейдем в home screen.

для примера это будет выглядеть так, что каждое и sms и dialer работают со своим экземпляром списка контактов и стек у каждого из них будет свой.

b) singleTop для активити D в данном случае ничем не отличается от standard. Эти режимы относятся к одному task'у и отличия standard от singleTop лишь в том, что если бы мы потом запустили активити D в том же таске и она была бы на вершине стека, новый экземпляр не создавался бы, а сработало бы onNewIntent для существующей активти. Например, такой вариант запуска активти применяется при реализации поиска... Короче говоря результат будет таким же как и в первом пункте.

пример естественно будет тот же.

c) режим singleTask для D говорит о том, что активити D запускается только в одном таске. Следовательно, при запуске D из Z произойдет смена таска на первый, далее нажимаем back, как только мы выйдем из стека таска 1, вернемся в таск 2 и будем выходить из него. При этом возврат на главный экран произойдет только в конце, т.е. когда оба таска опустеют.

Task1=ABCD, Task2=XYZ (D уже запущена в таске 1) ->
Task1=ABC, Task2=XYZ ->
Task1=AB, Task2=XYZ ->
Task1=A, Task2=XYZ ->
Task1=<умер>, Task2=XYZ ->
Task1=<умер>, Task2=XY ->
Task1=<умер>, Task2=X ->
home screen.

по примеру. если бы список контактов был singleTask (хоть это и бред), то зайдя в sms добравшись до списка, вернулись на домашний экран, открыли dialer, опять открыли список контактов, нажали back и оказались в sms 8-() жмем back, окзаываемся в dialer'е 8-()

Answer (score 3):

А я как раз таки попробую высказать небольшое предположение по поводу **3-его вопроса**.

Если отталкиваться от того, что Ваш ответ не был принят, хотя как мне кажется все вроде правильно написано, попробуем немного по другому посмотреть вот на это задание:

> Историю того, как будут изменяться стеки при нажатии кнопки BACK, пока не возвратимся в Home screen. Например: A,B,C,D - back -> A,B,C -back -> A,B - back -> A - back -> Home screen;

Как вариант, возможно здесь имелось ввиду привести изменение стеков до **первого** возврата на `Home screen`.

Тогда:

1. X,Y,Z,D - back -> X,Y,Z -back -> X,Y - back -> X - back -> Home screen;
2. X,Y,Z,D - back -> X,Y,Z -back -> X,Y - back -> X - back -> Home screen;
3. A,B,C,D - back -> A,B,C -back -> A,B - back -> A - back -> X,Y,Z - back -> X,Y -back -> X - back -> Home screen;

> И еще раз хочу сказать что это лишь предположение по поводу ответа на данный вопрос. Обязательно дайте знать если вдруг получите разъяснение по поводу данного вопроса.