# Найти проблемы в коде

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Получил задачу, найти все возможные проблемы в коде класса, но без объяснения, что считать проблемой, а что просто неудачным решением. Пока вижу только следующее:

1. Использование массива в качестве ключа, без переопределения методов
   equals и hashcode работать не будет.
2. Мар не иниизиализирован, всегда будет null.
3. Неоптимальный алгоритм, два раза проверяем одно и то же.
4. Синхронизацию лучше сделать через Collections.synchronizedMap(map).

Что я упустил?

И собственно сам код.

```
public abstract class Doing {

    private Map<byte[], byte[]> map = new HashMap<byte[], byte[]>();

    public byte[] doing(byte[] input) {

        byte[] result = map.get(input);

        if (result == null) {

            synchronized (map) {

                result = map.get(input);

                if (result == null) {

                    result = doSomething(input);

                    map.put(input, result);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract byte[] doSomething(byte[] input);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451929/190934

Comment: 1. а почему вы считаете, что они не определены? 2. инициализирован.

Comment: 1.  http://www.quizful.net/interview/java/byte-array-as-hashmap-key           2. инициализирован null

Comment: @Tariel вот вы сейчас серьезно?

Comment: @abbath0767   Ну да.  В чем я ошибаюсь?